# Почему получаю ошибку ERROR: No build artifacts found?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

Создаю библиотеку для android, при попытке опубликовать библиотеку на jitpack, получаю ошибку `ERROR: No build artifacts found $HOME/.m2/repository/com/github/buratinoapps/WSettings/1.0.` Вот логи https://jitpack.io/com/github/buratinoapps/WSettings/1.0/build.log

Не находит артефакты в папке `HOME` но у меня артефакты лежат в папке `C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository\com\github\buratinoapps\WSettings\1.0`

Вот build.gradle библиотеки

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication){
                from components.release
                groupId = 'com.github.buratinoapps' //your git id
                artifactId = 'WSettings' //your-repository
                version = '1.0' // As same as the Tag

                artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${artifactId}-release.aar") // here is difference, I used `from components...` before

                // use this if you're using third party in your lib
                pom.withXml {
                    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                    configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Может быть проблема в `[Fatal Error] lint-resources-release.xml:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.`? Можете показать содержимое файла `lint-resources-release.xml`?

Comment: У меня этого файла вообще нету. А ещё по какой то причине у меня перестала подключатся библиотека в моем проекте.

Comment: Вот тут 4 дня назад у кого-то [такая же проблема](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/5173) с `lint-resources-release.xml`, но ответа пока нет.

Answer (score 0):

В логе написано что вы накосячили с POM-файлом. Попробуйте убрать блок `pom.withXml {}`, думаю этот финт не требуется.
Вот с таким конфигом у меня спокойно публикуются несколько библиотек:

```
anroid {
    ...
    publishing {
        singleVariant('release')
    }
}

...

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId = 'com.example'
                artifactId = 'mylibrary'
                version = '1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Без этого блока тоже самое

Comment: Так сделайте минимальный чистый конфиг как у меня (со своими id, естественно), а уж после удачной публикации добавляйте что вам ещё не хватает